# ¿como iniciar un proyecto en Kataras iris?

Tags: go

Resulta que soy nueva en el Framework, y llevo un poco de tiempo entendiendo como manejar las vistas en Kataras/iris pero aun no logró crear mi pagina Index principal si alguien pudiera darme una página  o ejemplo de como construir la estructura del proyecto para comenzar a desarrollar en web se los agradecería mucho

Comment: la pagina del proyecto en Github tiene un buen de documentación
https://github.com/kataras/iris ,no se si ya le hayas echado un ojo

Answer (score 0):

Buenas en el mismo repo del proyecto encuentras ejemplos:

https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples/view

Comment: Douglas, pienso que tu respuesta se queda un poco corta no porque sea mala, sino porque la pregunta es muy mala. Lo mejor en el futuro sera reportar o comentar cuando tenga suficiente reputacion. Saludos.

Comment: Corta ? esta bien !